# How to format decimal numbers with StringTemplate (ST) in Java?

Tags: java, stringtemplate

I am using StringTemplate in Java.

I would like to render decimal number with a certain precision (e.g. 3 digits after the decimal point).

Is it possible to for the ST object to do it? And how?

Edit: 
to clarify, this is especially relevant when rendering objects. E.g. my code looks like

```
String renderMe(String template, Collection<MyClass> items)
{
  // render the items here using the template.... 
}
```

renderMe() doesn't have to know anything about the fields of MyClass, in particular it doesn't have to know which fields are floating points. I am looking for a solution that maintains this decoupling.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Register built-in NumberRenderer for Number subclasses and then use format option:

```
String template =
    "foo(x,y) ::= << <x; format=\"%,d\"> <y; format=\"%,2.3f\"> >>\n";
STGroup g = new STGroupString(template);
g.registerRenderer(Number.class, new NumberRenderer());
```

Comment: Consider also including the expected rendering of such a template.

Answer (score 3):

Not tested, but I guess something like this should work:

```
StringTemplate strTemp = new StringTemplate("Decimal number: $number$");
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
((DecimalFormat)nf).applyPattern("0.000");
strTemp.setAttribute("number", nf.format(123.45678));
System.out.println(strTemp);
```

Comment: +1 yes, it is not the `StringTemplate`'s responsibility to format any given value, as there are already existing classes to do that already.

Comment: That's what I have done, but I hoped I StringTemplate offered a shortcut for that.

Comment: I disagree. The Model's job is to provide a numerical value; the View's job is to decide how to present it. The number of decimal places is a presentation detail, not part of the logic or storage.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: stupid me, the link was directly above the one I gave. Use a [Renderer like the example given here](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ST4/Renderers).

If you know ahead of time which precisions will be needed, you can set up a Controller to handle those cases, and push them into the View.

splash suggested a way that this could be done. A somewhat more generic way might be something like the following:

```
class DoublePrecisionGetters {
  public double number;
  public NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();

  public DoublePrecisionGetters(double d)
  { number = d; }

  public String getTwoPlaces() {
    nf.applyPattern("0.00");
    return nf.format(number);
  }

  public String getThreePlaces() {
    nf.applyPattern("0.000");
    return nf.format(number);
  }

  // etc
}
```

You would setup ST like:

```
ST template = new ST("two places: $number.twoPlaces$", '$');
template.setAttribute("number", new DoublePrecisionGetters(3.14159));
```

Finally, if you really need it to be totally generic, you could hack something together with [model adaptors](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ST4/Model+adaptors) by registering a ModelAdaptor to handle doubles (or whatever), and having it figure out the precision based on the requested propertyName.